# Search an Item of Custom UITableCell and Filter using Swift 4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'am trying to implement search functionality in my UITableViewController. So I've added a Search Controller on top of the cell inside UITableView.

I've done this `UISearchBarDelegate` with my TableViewController.

Here is my code for filtering search text:

```
// This method updates filteredData based on the text in the Search Box
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    // When there is no text, filteredData is the same as the original data
    // When user has entered text into the search box
    // Use the filter method to iterate over all items in the data array
    // For each item, return true if the item should be included and false if the
    // item should NOT be included
    filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? OrderDetailsTabBarViewController.orderDetailsList : OrderDetailsTabBarViewController.orderDetailsList.filter { (item: OrderBookedSetterGetter) -> Bool in
        // If dataItem matches the searchText, return true to include it
        return item.BookedOrderId(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

But, it shows the error **Cannot call value of non-function type 'Int'** on **return item.BookedOrderId(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil** line.

**BookedOrderId** is an Int

Can anyone help me with this. I'm stuck here and not able to find anything.

Also, I followed this tutorial:

[Link Here](https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Search-Bar-Guide)

Thank You.

Comment: can you show me the cell for indexpath

Comment: you mean cell for row at indexPath ?

Comment: Can you share the prototype for BookedOrderId?

Comment: If `BookOrderId` is an `Int` you can't call a method on it like this. If anything it would be something like this : `item.BookOrderId.methodName(arguments)`. Have you defined the method you are trying to call as an extension to `Int` anywhere?

Comment: prototype? do you mean model class?

Comment: I havn't defined any method.

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: What are you using for storing order details?

Comment: Array or something else?

Comment: @tdakus array, "static var orderCancelledDetailsList: [OrderBookedSetterGetter] = []" then I use append.

Comment: you should post implemention of `BookedOrderId(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil)` function/method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did and it works!

Use copy of your original data and use it over view controller

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        // When there is no text, filteredData is the same as the original data
        // When user has entered text into the search box
        // Use the filter method to iterate over all items in the data array
        // For each item, return true if the item should be included and false if the
        // item should NOT be included


            self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true

            self.copied_order_Canceled_DetailList = []
            for item in self.order_Canceled_DetailList {
            if String(item.orderId).localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) != false{
               self.copied_order_Canceled_DetailList.append(item))
            } else {

                }
            }

            self.tableview.reloadData()
            if searchText == "" {
                self.copied_order_Canceled_DetailList = self.order_Canceled_DetailList
                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }
        }
```

This should work.

Comment: "if item.BookedOrderId.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) != false {" I got an error in this line which says "Value of type 'Int' has no member 'localizedCaseInsensitiveContains"

Comment: Okay so the error is gone, but the list is the same. Where do I put this "self.copied_order_Canceled_DetailList = []" after filteration..?

Comment: Wherever you want to show data use self.copied_order_Canceled_DetailList

Comment: That means perform all operations on self.copied_order_Canceled_DetailList

Comment: Okay, Thanks for your support in the question, The filtering happens but only for the exact value.. For example is I have values as 345, 346, 347 and if I type 3 it doesn't show me count as 3 instead it shows 0 when I give exactly like 345 then it shows 1.. I shouldn't happen like that actually.

Comment: Replace if String(item.orderId) == searchText {
                    self.copied_order_Canceled_DetailList.append(item)
                }.  WITH if String(item.orderId).localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) != false{
                   self.copied_order_Canceled_DetailList.append(item))
                }

Comment: Okay but how will I apply this new list on my table.. as I've already applied my  table in cellForRow.. I'm sorry, I'm an Android developer just started with iOS few days ago and this is very new to me.. I appreciate if you help..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178927/discussion-between-tdakus-and-umang-burman).

Comment: Thanks, for helping me and solving so many queries related to iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean `range(of...`. To use that you have to convert the `Int` to `String`

```
filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? OrderDetailsTabBarViewController.orderDetailsList : OrderDetailsTabBarViewController.orderDetailsList.filter { (item: OrderBookedSetterGetter) -> Bool in
    // If dataItem matches the searchText, return true to include it
    let stringOrderId = String(item.BookedOrderId)
    return stringOrderId.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks the error is gone, but, now nothing is working. I mean when I run it in Simulator, and type BookedOrderId in SearchController, nothing happens. It's not filtering based on the OrderId.

Comment: I just answered the question to get rid of the error . I'm not responsible for your design 